# bootstrap breadcrumbs not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, breadcrumbs

I'm using bootstrap v3.3.7 
The `li` items of breadcrumbs are no showing when I use inspect element. What could be the reason?

```
<div class="row module-header">
 <div class="col-md-8">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
   <li><a href="#">Course Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Module Name</a></li>
   <li class="active">Chapter Name</li>
  </ol>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 </div>
</div>
```

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.responsiveTabs.js"></script>
```

What is actually displayed, just background with no text showing up

[image]

Comment: It runs perfectly when reproduced on Jsbin.com . What else you have done that you have not shown us?.

Comment: Where you have placed your css links and script links in your page or project?